# How to play videos on Google Colab while using openCV?

Tags: python, opencv, google-colaboratory

I have uploaded a video file to Google Colab, but I am not able to display it.

I tried :

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow


cap = cv2.VideoCapture('video.mp4')

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    cv2_imshow(frame)
```

**But this only made all the frames of the video to be displayed.**

Comment: First of all, did you mean `video.mp4` not `video.p4`?

Comment: Yeah, my bad. It is `video.mp4`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To upload video:

```
from google.colab import files
files.upload()
```

To view video:

```
from IPython.display import HTML
from base64 import b64encode
video_path = 'video_name.mp4'

mp4 = open(video_path,'rb').read()
decoded_vid = "data:video/mp4;base64," + b64encode(mp4).decode()
HTML(f'<video width=400 controls><source src={decoded_vid} type="video/mp4"></video>')
```